# Django - Crispy Forms - Custom input positioning and inline radio buttons

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

I have been working with django-crispy-forms a while ago and **I want to know if there is a way to set the positioning of the inputs like the `col-md-XX` classes or something to make it looks better and not just like a list of fields.**

Here is an example:

This is a "normal" render of a crispy-form using `{{ form | crispy }}` or `{% crispy form %}`
[image]

I want to be rendered like this with python code in the forms.py or something like that. Actually I make this by typing HTML code and rendering with `as_crispy_field` tag.
[image]

Finally when I render the form with `{% crispy form %}` I can have the radio buttons with inline style, but with `as_crispy_field` tag, the radios still looking vertical, even with the `InlineRadios` layout in the helper.

With `as_crispy_field`
[image]

With `{% crispy form %}`
[image]

**Is there a way to make radios looks horizontal or inline with `as_crispy_field` tag?**

Answer (score 6):

You can use crispy InlineRadio [Layouts — django-crispy-forms 1.0.0 documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html?highlight=inlineradio#bootstrap-layout-objects)

```
class ProgramaForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['programa']

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgramaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['programa'].required = True
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Div(InlineRadios('programa')),
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

[Horizontal Radio Buttons For Boolean Values Using Crispy Forms with Django](https://gist.github.com/linxuedong/e559b437a0b7d4dd6f6cd8a6d1a26e77)

Comment: I am getting error
'InlineRadios' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'. This attribute is used in the default template.